# How does opt-out of a tracking-pixel site work?

Tags: cookies, web, tracking, privacy

So i found a tracking pixel from this site www.scorecardresearch.com, and they offer an opt-out from their Program.
My question is: How do could they do this, how would they know i've opt-ed out after i closed the session(there are no cookies set from this site)?